# Using both controller and require option inside angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to access **both** controllers inside the directive.
Currently it's not working and I don't know why or if it's even possible.

If I  use both `require` and `controller` option, inside the `link` function `ctrl` property refers to whatever I requested via the `require` option.

I can't think of a way to access the controller inside the `link` function when the `require` option is present.

It seems that these two properties are mutually exclusive ?

```
angular.module('moduleName').directive('directiveName', [function () {

    return {
    controller: 'MediaController',
    require:'ngController',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {

        // I need access to both controllers here

    }

}
```

}]);

Comment: Not mutually exclusive, they do different things. The directive's controller is never the "ctrl" param to the link function. It is either the one you "require" or it is not there. If you need to share data and functions between the controller and link functions, then just include them in the directive outside of the return object.

Comment: @aet "The directive's controller is never the "ctrl" param to the link function" - That's wrong. Read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both controllers, then require both controllers:

```
angular.module('moduleName').directive('directiveName', [function () {

return {
controller: MediaController,
require:['directiveName', 'ngController'],
```

In this case `ctrl` is an array containing the two controllers.

Comment: I need access to `MediaController` not controllers on other directives.

Comment: @IvanV. `MediaController` **IS** the controller of your directive.

Comment: Okay that works. First time a read it I glanced through and didn't see that you are referring to directive itself.Is this a hack or this is a valid think to do in AngularJs? I haven't seen this anywhere else ( directive requiring itself).

Comment: @IvanV. It's even used by angular itself for some directives. E.g. `ng-model` has `require: ['ngModel', '^?form']`. So no, it's not a hack :)

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing why you need to access both controllers, I can only offer minimal advice here.  My suggestion would be to create a service to handle cross controller needs.  Services are singletons and they support data binding.  Services are my preference for cross controller work every day.  For example:

```
App.controller('Ctrl1', function Ctrl1 ($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.someValue = TestService.getValue();
});

App.controller('Ctrl2', function Ctrl2 ($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.someValue = TestService.getValue();
});

App.factory('TestService', function() {
    var myVal = "I Bound";

    return {
        getValue: function() {
            return myVal;
        }
    }
});
```

This method allows you to abstract a controllers need to directly access another controller.  Your services can be pulled into these directives or other services too.  I hope this helps a bit.

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Well maybe what I'm trying to do can be done in some other way.

Comment: Well maybe what I'm trying to do can be done in some other way. I'm fairly new to angular.


Let's say I have a directive that represents a base media component (`<media-component>`)


I also have `video component` 'sound component` `X component` etc...
And I'm trying to have as little as possible code repetition, so I'm thinking of some kind of component/controller inheritance.
So the `basic` component has methods for `playing` and `stopping` and then the `video` component extends those methods to playing and stopping video source, `music` component for playing/stopping music etc...